# Highcharts - Hide child labels in a multiple levels and multiple layouts treemap

Tags: layout, highcharts, label, treemap, levels

On highcharts, I have a **treemap** with **2 levels**, each with a **different layout algorithm**. Now I want to limit what we can see to the current level. It means that on level 1, **I don't want to see the labels of level 2**, which would only appear when drilling down (and the labels of level 1 would disappear).

I know it is easy with `levelIsConstant: false`, but this only works with 1 level, and I use 2 because I need different layouts.

Here is the link to what I currently have:

```
series: [{
  type: "treemap",
  allowDrillToNode: true,
  alternateStartingDirection: true,
  levels: [{
    level: 1,
    layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'left',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      style: {
        fontSize: '15px',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    }
  }, {
    level: 2,
    layoutAlgorithm: 'stripes',
    color: 'blue'
  }],
  //...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dhfera2y/2/

I want all the names to be hidden, as well as the lines separating them.

*EDIT:* Using a rgba color on each level, I can hide the nodes below it, but I still cannot hide their label!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you it is a smart idea for the labels issue, but as I say I cannot use *levelIsConstant: false* because I need a different layout for each level at every moment. With this solution both levels can have a different layout when I am on the top level, but I soon as I drill down I loose the correct layout for the new view.

Almost :-)

**EDIT :** Okay so I finally managed to do it. I think it is impossible to achieve this in the way I was trying to, which was using the *parent* option for each child point of the serie in order to determine the hierarchy of the tree. So instead of using one serie with a hierarchy, I use one serie for the top level which I link to several series for the level below. 
I was able the do this thanks to the *drilldown* option.

I found the solution in the official documentation :
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/drilldown

I adjusted the code and it was all right. Here is the solution I came up with (it is a different work from my first link) :
http://jsfiddle.net/ff964fog/47/

```
series: [{
      type: 'treemap',
      layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
      borderWidth: 3,
      data: modulesData
    }],
    drilldown: {
      series: servicesSerie
    },
```

I still have to adjust a few things (like the disappearance of the animations for the bottom level), but in the end I have exactly what I wanted !

Answer (score 1):

My take on some settings you can use to achieve this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhfera2y/3/)):

```
series: [{
    type: "treemap",
    allowDrillToNode: true,
    levelIsConstant: false,
    // ...
    levels: [{
        level: 1,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
        // ...
    }, {
        level: 2,
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }],
    data[{
        //...
    }]
}]
```

The level 2 settings apply only when viewing from level 1. When drilling down the new view is considered to be level 1 because of `levelIsConstant: false`.

Setting `borderWidth: 0` in level 2 is only needed if you want to hide the grid of level 2 when viewing from level 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom formatter for `plotOptions.treemap.datalabels`. The code bellow is an example that uses `this.series.rootNode` and `this.point.parent` and compare them to examine if the label should be shown or not:

```
plotOptions: {
    treemap: {
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function(data) {
          if (this.point.parent == (this.series.rootNode || null)) {
            return this.key;
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

You can use any other property that is available in formatter function. Just log (`console.log`) `this` and `data` in the formatter function to see all the properties available:

```
plotOptions: {
    treemap: {
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function(data) {
          console.log(this, data);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of @halvor-holsten-strand I think it is best to use `levelIsConstant: false`, disable the data labels in general and then overwrite the level config for level 1. Otherwise you will have to add n-1 level configs with data labels disabled.

```js
{
  chart: {
    type: 'treemap',
  },
  plotOptions: {
    treemap: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false, // Disable data labels for all levels
      },
    },
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'lorem ipsum',
      allowDrillToNode: true,
      levelIsConstant: false,
      levels: [{
        level: 1,
        borderWidth: 1,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true, // Enable data labels for level 1
        },
      }],
      data: [/* ... */],
    },
  ],
}
```